# System Problem Detected Window not reporting problem

Tags: 14.04

So I've been getting the System Problem Detected Popup now and then, but whenever I hit "Report Problem" it just closes. Any way I can run a command to view the issue, or fix this? Thanks in advance. I'm on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: It's almost always some weird error with `Xorg` if anything, and it's never actually a problem. I've found that dialog box comes up after either a large update or after the installation of a new desktop environment. Unless you actually experience problems, just dismiss and ignore it.